# apply function that uses column as input on a column with conditioning

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have two groups: '1' and '2'.

```
ls = [
    ['1', 2],
    ['2', 7],
    ['1', 3],
    ['2',-6],
    ['1', 3],
    ['1', 5],
    ['1', 4],
    ['2', 7]
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=['col1', 'col2']))
df.show()

+----+-----+
|col1| col2|
+----+-----+
|   1|    2|
|   2|    7|
|   1|    3|
|   2|   -6|
|   1|    3|
|   1|    5|
|   1|    4|
|   2|    7|
+----+-----+
```

I have computed QuantileDiscretizer() for each group using:

```
discretizer = QuantileDiscretizer(numBuckets=3, inputCol="col2", outputCol="result")
bucketizer_1 = discretizer.fit(df.filter(col('col1')=='1'))
bucketizer_2 = discretizer.fit(df.filter(col('col1')=='2'))
```

These bucketizers are stored in a list, so I can call them using indexing (bucketizers[0], bucketizers[1])

Now I'm trying to transform the data in col2 into quantiles using the bucketizers. In other words, if col1 == '1', then bucketizers[0].transform(data) -> store result in a new column of the dataframe. Same process for group '2' but with bucketizers[1].

(Let's disregard the reason why I didn't fit and transform the data in one go)

I'm struggling to write the code to obtain what I want, since transform() uses a column as input.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is using an [union](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union):

```py
bucketizers[0].transform(df.filter((F.col('col1')=='1'))).union(bucketizers[1].transform(df.filter(F.col('col1')=='2'))).show()
```